# How to update a specific data of a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a likes/dislikes thing in php & html. So, since it uses likes for each blog, I use the blog ID. I would like to know how I could update the "likes" in the table, but only update the "likes" of the specific row using it's id. Here is the php script:

```
<?php

require 'init.php';

$rating = $_GET['rating'];
$postid = $_GET['id'];

if ($rating = "like") {
    $sql = "

    ";
}

if ($rating = "dislike") {
    $sql = "
        UPDATE
            posts
        SET
            dislikes = dislikes+1
        WHERE
            id = $postid    
    ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The update query does not seem to be the problem here, the main problem is your if statement, where you are not using comparison operator but are using assignment operator.

The statement: `if ($rating = "like")` assigns value `"like"` to the variable `$rating`, it does not compare `$rating` against value `"like"`, which is what I think you want it to do.

There are few other "major" issues to note is that you are wide open for SQL Injection attacks.  Since you mentioned that you are using `mysql_` functions in your comment, you at least want to make use of `mysql_real_escape_string` function.  e.g.

```
$rating = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rating'], $con); // assuming $con is your MySQL Connection
$postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $con);
```

Another equally important point to note is that `mysql_` functions are deprecated.  You definitely should consider using either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Third and final point to note is that if your rating is `"like"` then the query is empty.  Hopefully you are checking for `empty`ness before calling `mysql_query`, which is not shown here.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a newbish error. I forgot to add "mysql_query($sql)". Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: @JamesL. But Vinodadhikary is still right: you are using `=` in your if-statements when you should be using `==`. Watch out for that, because as it stands, your if-statements will always return true.

Comment: No, they return false too. When a link is clicked, is sends "dislike" or "like". But I agree, I should use escape string because someone could hack it.